# How to prevent right-most element from jumping on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm satisfied with this except for when hovering over the right-most image (must click show images to see images). The whole row jumps slightly to the left. I noticed this does not happen on the last row. Any pointers are appreciated.

Here is a codepen that demonstrates the issue: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OmeNRa?editors=0110

```js
var showImages = $("#showImages");
var hideImages = $("#hideImages");
var images = $("#images");
var overlay = $("#overlay");
var docHeight = $(document).height();
var writtenContent = $("#writtenContent");
var counter = 0;
var messageBox = $("#messageBox");
var sendMessage = $("#sendMessage");

showImages.click(function() {
  counter++;
  $(this).html("Show Images");
  if (counter % 2 > 0) $(this).html("Hide Images");
  $("body").toggleClass("blackout", 300);
  images.slideToggle({
    direction: "up"
  }, 600);
  writtenContent.slideToggle({
    direction: "up"
  }, 600);
});

sendMessage.click(function() {
  messageBox.slideToggle({
    direction: "up"
  }, 500);
});

$(document).on("mouseenter", "span img", function() {
  $(this).addClass("fade").siblings().show();
});
$(document).on("mouseleave", "span img", function() {
  $(this).removeClass("fade").siblings().hide();
});
```

```css
.nav {
  height: 8vh;
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, purple, purple, indigo);
  color: white;
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
}

#topNav {
  top: 0vh;
}

#bottomNav {
  bottom: -8.1vh;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}

#content {
  padding-top: 8vh;
  padding-bottom: 8vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#images {
  display: none;
  z-index: 100;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#images span {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

#images span img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.blackout {
  background-color: black;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.name {
  display: none;
  color: white;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 200%;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.fade {
  opacity: .2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav" id="topNav">
</div>
<div id="content">
  <div id="writtenContent">
    <p>This page's written content starts here..</p>
    <p>Page written content goes here.</p>
    <p>Page written content goes here.</p>
    <p>Page written content goes here.</p>
    <p>Page written content goes here.</p>
    <p>Page written content goes here.</p>
    <p>Page written content goes here.</p>
    <p>Page written content goes here.</p>
    <p>Page written content goes here.</p>
    <p>Page written content goes here.</p>
    <p>Page written content goes here.</p>
    <p>Page written content goes here.</p>
    <p>Page written content goes here.</p>
    <p>Page written content goes here.</p>
    <p>Page written content goes here.</p>
    <p>Page written content goes here.</p>
    <p>Page written content goes here.</p>
    <p>Page written content goes here.</p>
    <p>Page written content goes here.</p>
    <p>Page written content goes here.</p>
    <p>Page written content goes here.</p>
    <p>Page written content goes here.</p>
    <p>Page written content goes here.</p>
    <p>Page written content goes here.</p>
    <p>Page written content goes here.</p>
    <p>END of page's written content.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="images">
    <span>
          <img src="https://pp.walk.sc/map_tiles/walkscore/v3/17/4512/6478/14.png">
          <div class='name'>Image Title</div>
        </span>
    <span>
          <img src="https://pp.walk.sc/map_tiles/walkscore/v3/17/4512/6478/14.png">
          <div class='name'>Image Title</div>
        </span>
    <span>
          <img src="https://pp.walk.sc/map_tiles/walkscore/v3/17/4512/6478/14.png">
          <div class='name'>Image Title</div>
        </span>
    <span>
          <img src="https://pp.walk.sc/map_tiles/walkscore/v3/17/4512/6478/14.png">
          <div class='name'>Image Title</div>
        </span>
    <span>
          <img src="https://pp.walk.sc/map_tiles/walkscore/v3/17/4512/6478/14.png">
          <div class='name'>Image Title</div>
        </span>
    <span>
          <img src="https://pp.walk.sc/map_tiles/walkscore/v3/17/4512/6478/14.png">
          <div class='name'>Image Title</div>
        </span>
    <span>
          <img src="https://pp.walk.sc/map_tiles/walkscore/v3/17/4512/6478/14.png">
          <div class='name'>Image LONG LONG LONG Title</div>
        </span>
    <span>
          <img src="https://pp.walk.sc/map_tiles/walkscore/v3/17/4512/6478/14.png">
          <div class='name'>Image Title</div>
        </span>
    <span>
          <img src="https://pp.walk.sc/map_tiles/walkscore/v3/17/4512/6478/14.png">
          <div class='name'>Image LONG LONG Title</div>
        </span>
    <span>
          <img src="https://pp.walk.sc/map_tiles/walkscore/v3/17/4512/6478/14.png">
          <div class='name'>Image Title</div>
        </span>
    <span>
          <img src="https://pp.walk.sc/map_tiles/walkscore/v3/17/4512/6478/14.png">
          <div class='name'>Image Title</div>
        </span>
    <span>
          <img src="https://pp.walk.sc/map_tiles/walkscore/v3/17/4512/6478/14.png">
          <div class='name'>Image LONG Title</div>
        </span>
    <span>
          <img src="https://pp.walk.sc/map_tiles/walkscore/v3/17/4512/6478/14.png">
          <div class='name'>Image Title</div>
        </span>
    <span>
          <img src="https://pp.walk.sc/map_tiles/walkscore/v3/17/4512/6478/14.png">
          <div class='name'>Image Title</div>
        </span>
    <span>
          <img src="https://pp.walk.sc/map_tiles/walkscore/v3/17/4512/6478/14.png">
          <div class='name'>Image Title</div>
        </span>
    <span>
          <img src="https://pp.walk.sc/map_tiles/walkscore/v3/17/4512/6478/14.png">
          <div class='name'>Image Title</div>
        </span>
    <span>
          <img src="https://pp.walk.sc/map_tiles/walkscore/v3/17/4512/6478/14.png">
          <div class='name'>Image Title</div>
        </span>
    <span>
          <img src="https://pp.walk.sc/map_tiles/walkscore/v3/17/4512/6478/14.png">
          <div class='name'>Image Title</div>
        </span>
    <span>
          <img src="https://pp.walk.sc/map_tiles/walkscore/v3/17/4512/6478/14.png">
          <div class='name'>Image Title</div>
        </span>
    <span>
          <img src="https://pp.walk.sc/map_tiles/walkscore/v3/17/4512/6478/14.png">
          <div class='name'>Image Title</div>
        </span>
    <span>
          <img src="https://pp.walk.sc/map_tiles/walkscore/v3/17/4512/6478/14.png">
          <div class='name'>Image Title</div>
        </span>
    <span>
          <img src="https://pp.walk.sc/map_tiles/walkscore/v3/17/4512/6478/14.png">
          <div class='name'>Image Title</div>
        </span>
    <span>
          <img src="https://pp.walk.sc/map_tiles/walkscore/v3/17/4512/6478/14.png">
          <div class='name'>Image Title</div>
        </span>
    <span>
          <img src="https://pp.walk.sc/map_tiles/walkscore/v3/17/4512/6478/14.png">
          <div class='name'>Image Title</div>
        </span>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="nav" id="bottomNav">
  <button id="showImages">Show Images</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You could do all this hovering stuff with CSS a lot more reliably; also you should not have `<div>` inside `<span>`.

Comment: @miken32 thanks, I changed the divs inside the spans to spans. Looking into CSS3 hovering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lays with the fact your `.images>span` have `display:inline` (default). Also your centering technique is based on the height of the inline span, which is dependent on line-height and can so easily break, nevermind proper centering (if, for example, you change the height of your images).

To fix your problem, I'd do this:

```
#images span {
  display: inline-block;
}
.name {
  bottom: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translateY(50%)
}
```

Your updated snippet:

```js
var showImages = $("#showImages");
var hideImages = $("#hideImages");
var images = $("#images");
var overlay = $("#overlay");
var docHeight = $(document).height();
var writtenContent = $("#writtenContent");
var counter = 0;
var messageBox = $("#messageBox");
var sendMessage = $("#sendMessage");

showImages.click(function() {
  counter++;
  $(this).html("Show Images");
  if (counter % 2 > 0) $(this).html("Hide Images");
  $("body").toggleClass("blackout", 300);
  images.slideToggle({
    direction: "up"
  }, 600);
  writtenContent.slideToggle({
    direction: "up"
  }, 600);
});

sendMessage.click(function() {
  messageBox.slideToggle({
    direction: "up"
  }, 500);
});

$(document).on("mouseenter", "span img", function() {
  $(this).addClass("fade").siblings().show();
});
$(document).on("mouseleave", "span img", function() {
  $(this).removeClass("fade").siblings().hide();
});
```

```css
.nav {
  height: 8vh;
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, purple, purple, indigo);
  color: white;
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
}

#topNav {
  top: 0vh;
}

#bottomNav {
  bottom: -8.1vh;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}

#content {
  padding-top: 8vh;
  padding-bottom: 8vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#images {
  display: none;
  z-index: 100;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#images span {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
   display: inline-block;
}

#images span img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.blackout {
  background-color: black;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.name {
  display: none;
  color: white;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  pointer-events: none;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translateY(50%)
}

.fade {
  opacity: .2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav" id="topNav">
</div>
<div id="content">
  <div id="writtenContent">
    <p>This page's written content starts here..</p>
    <p>Page written content goes here.</p>
    <p>Page written content goes here.</p>
    <p>Page written content goes here.</p>
    <p>Page written content goes here.</p>
    <p>Page written content goes here.</p>
    <p>Page written content goes here.</p>
    <p>Page written content goes here.</p>
    <p>Page written content goes here.</p>
    <p>Page written content goes here.</p>
    <p>Page written content goes here.</p>
    <p>Page written content goes here.</p>
    <p>Page written content goes here.</p>
    <p>Page written content goes here.</p>
    <p>Page written content goes here.</p>
    <p>Page written content goes here.</p>
    <p>Page written content goes here.</p>
    <p>Page written content goes here.</p>
    <p>Page written content goes here.</p>
    <p>Page written content goes here.</p>
    <p>Page written content goes here.</p>
    <p>Page written content goes here.</p>
    <p>Page written content goes here.</p>
    <p>Page written content goes here.</p>
    <p>Page written content goes here.</p>
    <p>END of page's written content.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="images">
    <span>
          <img src="https://pp.walk.sc/map_tiles/walkscore/v3/17/4512/6478/14.png">
          <div class='name'>Image Title</div>
        </span>
    <span>
          <img src="https://pp.walk.sc/map_tiles/walkscore/v3/17/4512/6478/14.png">
          <div class='name'>Image Title</div>
        </span>
    <span>
          <img src="https://pp.walk.sc/map_tiles/walkscore/v3/17/4512/6478/14.png">
          <div class='name'>Image Title</div>
        </span>
    <span>
          <img src="https://pp.walk.sc/map_tiles/walkscore/v3/17/4512/6478/14.png">
          <div class='name'>Image Title</div>
        </span>
    <span>
          <img src="https://pp.walk.sc/map_tiles/walkscore/v3/17/4512/6478/14.png">
          <div class='name'>Image Title</div>
        </span>
    <span>
          <img src="https://pp.walk.sc/map_tiles/walkscore/v3/17/4512/6478/14.png">
          <div class='name'>Image Title</div>
        </span>
    <span>
          <img src="https://pp.walk.sc/map_tiles/walkscore/v3/17/4512/6478/14.png">
          <div class='name'>Image LONG LONG LONG Title</div>
        </span>
    <span>
          <img src="https://pp.walk.sc/map_tiles/walkscore/v3/17/4512/6478/14.png">
          <div class='name'>Image Title</div>
        </span>
    <span>
          <img src="https://pp.walk.sc/map_tiles/walkscore/v3/17/4512/6478/14.png">
          <div class='name'>Image LONG LONG Title</div>
        </span>
    <span>
          <img src="https://pp.walk.sc/map_tiles/walkscore/v3/17/4512/6478/14.png">
          <div class='name'>Image Title</div>
        </span>
    <span>
          <img src="https://pp.walk.sc/map_tiles/walkscore/v3/17/4512/6478/14.png">
          <div class='name'>Image Title</div>
        </span>
    <span>
          <img src="https://pp.walk.sc/map_tiles/walkscore/v3/17/4512/6478/14.png">
          <div class='name'>Image LONG Title</div>
        </span>
    <span>
          <img src="https://pp.walk.sc/map_tiles/walkscore/v3/17/4512/6478/14.png">
          <div class='name'>Image Title</div>
        </span>
    <span>
          <img src="https://pp.walk.sc/map_tiles/walkscore/v3/17/4512/6478/14.png">
          <div class='name'>Image Title</div>
        </span>
    <span>
          <img src="https://pp.walk.sc/map_tiles/walkscore/v3/17/4512/6478/14.png">
          <div class='name'>Image Title</div>
        </span>
    <span>
          <img src="https://pp.walk.sc/map_tiles/walkscore/v3/17/4512/6478/14.png">
          <div class='name'>Image Title</div>
        </span>
    <span>
          <img src="https://pp.walk.sc/map_tiles/walkscore/v3/17/4512/6478/14.png">
          <div class='name'>Image Title</div>
        </span>
    <span>
          <img src="https://pp.walk.sc/map_tiles/walkscore/v3/17/4512/6478/14.png">
          <div class='name'>Image Title</div>
        </span>
    <span>
          <img src="https://pp.walk.sc/map_tiles/walkscore/v3/17/4512/6478/14.png">
          <div class='name'>Image Title</div>
        </span>
    <span>
          <img src="https://pp.walk.sc/map_tiles/walkscore/v3/17/4512/6478/14.png">
          <div class='name'>Image Title</div>
        </span>
    <span>
          <img src="https://pp.walk.sc/map_tiles/walkscore/v3/17/4512/6478/14.png">
          <div class='name'>Image Title</div>
        </span>
    <span>
          <img src="https://pp.walk.sc/map_tiles/walkscore/v3/17/4512/6478/14.png">
          <div class='name'>Image Title</div>
        </span>
    <span>
          <img src="https://pp.walk.sc/map_tiles/walkscore/v3/17/4512/6478/14.png">
          <div class='name'>Image Title</div>
        </span>
    <span>
          <img src="https://pp.walk.sc/map_tiles/walkscore/v3/17/4512/6478/14.png">
          <div class='name'>Image Title</div>
        </span>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="nav" id="bottomNav">
  <button id="showImages">Show Images</button>
</div>
```

Also note `<div>`s inside `<span>` elements are technically, illegal. However, it's an error so widely spread that it's likely this rule will be bent in the future. But, for now, if you want your page to validate, you need to change your markup.

Comment: Thanks, this did it.

Answer (score 0):

The content of the line is being re-centered. When you change the CSS as below the issue doesn't occur.

```
#images{
 display:none;
 z-index:100;
 bottom:0;
 text-align:left; /* instead of center */
}
```